# Updating views using set command in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

I am trying to teach myself SQL and have become stuck.

I am using the standard demo table that Oracle provides ([seen here](http://www.in-oracle.com/pictures/Database/backup-recovery/P_data_back.PNG)).

Say if I create two identical views:

```
create view view_a_emp as
select empno, ename, job
from emp
where job = 'CLERK';
```

and

```
create view view_b_emp as
select empno, ename, job
from emp
where job = 'CLERK';
```

I will get 4 rows returned for each of them.

If I update view_b_emp, like so:

```
update view_b_emp
set job = 'ASSISTANT';
```

Now neither of the two views return any rows AND the underlying base table has been modified (all "Clerks" are now "Assistants").

It's obvious that I am misunderstanding how views work, but I thought the idea of a view was to provide a virtual table.

Could anyone shed some light as to why updating and setting an attribute on one view changes the underlying table?

Comment: Read about views: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/schemaob.htm#CNCPT311

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works! A view is nothing more than a stored query.

If you wish to prevent updates to the views from conflicting with the view's definition, you can add `with check option` to the view.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF54792

Comment: I am going to split some hairs on this one because it is critical to understand.  A view is simply a query that you can invoke, it is not stored in the sense that Oracle caches it.  For example if you have a long running query as part of a view Oracle will execute that query everytime and not store the results as it would in a `materialized view`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, guys. I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Because its linked to the underlying Table, modifying a Tables view will modify its underlying table.
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=130855&seqNum=4